# Code to download this link with PHP curl

Tags: php, curl

This link

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/11121#DownloadId=28808

shows a popup on which one has to agree before being able to download.

So how to automate this with PHP curl ? Any existing similar sample code  ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Because I'm working for big enterprises and want to automate downloads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at what's happening when you click on the "I agree" button with a tool like [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829), you'll see that :

- When you click on the "*I agreee*" button, it sends an HTTP POST request

  - to `http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/acceptLicense`
- That HTTP request returns a `302` response,

  - with a `Location` HTTP header that points to `http://download.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=AjaxControlToolkit&DownloadId=28807&FileTime=128487916929600000&Build=16331`
  - which is the adress from which your browser is actually downloading the file.

*(see there for the [HTTP headers of that exchange](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/headers-question-2438608.txt))*

It doesn't seem to be any other kind of control/security... 

So, downloading from that URL with curl should work, I'd say.